# Is there any Mysql communication protocols libs or documents?

Tags: mysql, sockets

We're thinging of making a middleware for mysql in our project, which we hope it could act exactlly like a mysql-server at socket level.

Is there any kind of libs, documents or articles related to this task?

Comment: you would have googled it before posting....this here!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be found on mysql site.

#### [Chapter 15. MySQL Client/Server Protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html)

Comment: Thans very much for this in time help. And, is there any libs dealing this kind of work in c/c++/node.js?